# Can upcasting a shared_ptr<T> to a shared_ptr<void> lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, void-pointers

Shared pointers are quite smart. They remember the type they where first constructed with in order to delete them correctly. Take that for example:

```
struct A { virtual void test() = 0; };
struct B : A { void test() override {} };

void someFunc() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> ptr1;

    ptr1 = std::make_shared<B>();

    // Here at the end of the scope, B is deleted correctly
}
```

However, there seems to be a problem with void pointers: for a downcast of a void pointer to be valid, one must downcast it to the type it was originally upcasted from.

For example:

```
void* myB = new B;

// Okay, well defined
doStuff(static_cast<B*>(myB));

// uh oh, not good!
// For the same instance of a child object, a pointer to the base and
// a pointer to the child can be differrent.
doStuff(static_cast<A*>(myB));
```

With `std::shared_ptr`, when you use `std::make_shared`, the deleter must look similar to this function: `[](B* ptr){ delete ptr; }`. Since the pointer (in the first example) is holding a `B` instance in a pointer to `A` and deletes it correctly, it must downcast it in some way.

My question is: is the following code snippet invokes undefined behaviour?

```
void someFunc() {
    {
        std::shared_ptr<void> ptr = std::make_shared<B>();

        // Deleting the pointer seems okay to me,
        // the shared_ptr knows that a B was originally allocated with a B and
        // will send the void pointer to the deleter that's delete a B.
    }

    std::shared_ptr<void> vptr;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_shared<B>();

        // ptr is pointing to the base, which can be 
        // different address than the pointer to the child.

        // assigning the pointer to the base to the void pointer.
        // according to my current knowledge of void pointers, 
        // any future use of the pointer must cast it to a A* or end up in UB.
        vptr = ptr;
    }

    // is the pointer deleted correctly or it tries to
    // cast the void pointer to a B pointer without downcasting to a A* first?
    // Or is it well defined and std::shared_ptr uses some dark magic unknown to me?
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code is correct.

`std::shared_ptr` internally saves the real pointer and the real deleter as they are in the constructor, so no matter how you downcast it, as long as the downcast is valid the deleter will be right.

The `shared_ptr` actually does not hold a pointer to the object, but a pointer to an intermediate struct that holds the actual object, the reference counter and the deleter. It doesn't matter if you cast the `shared_ptr`, that intermediate struct does not change. It cannot change because your `vptr` and `ptr`, although of different types, share the reference counter (and the object and the deleter, of course).

BTW, that intermediate struct is the reason for the `make_shared` optimization: it allocates both the intermediate struct and the object itself in the same memory block and avoids the extra allocation.

To illustrate how smart pointers can be, I have written a program with plain pointers that crashes (with GCC 6.2.1) because of your problem:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a;
    A() :a(1) {}
    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "~A " << a << std::endl;
    }
};

struct X
{
    int x;
    X() :x(3) {}
    ~X()
    {
        std::cout << "~X " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B : X, A
{
    int b;
    B() : b(2) {}
    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "~B " << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A* a = new B;
    void * v = a;
    delete (B*)v; //crash!

    return 0;    
}
```

Actually it prints the wrong integer values, which proves the UB.

```
~B 0
~A 2
~X 1
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000001629c24 ***
```

But the version with smart pointers works just fine:

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<void> vptr;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<A> ptr = std::make_shared<B>();
        vptr = ptr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints as expected:

```
~B 2
~A 1
~X 3
```

Comment: I will always upvote a correct answer that conveys the design perfection of the shared_ptr. +1 :)

Comment: @RichardHodges I prefer `std::unique_ptr` as they are free in term of overhead ;). As for the answer, good job @rodrigo, it pretty much covers everything.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` *does* hold a pointer, the one returned from `shared_ptr::get()`.  But this is not the same pointer that is passed to the deleter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @BenVoigt. I guess the deleter and the pointer to be deleted must be held in the control block, and the one returned `shared_ptr::get()` in the shared pointer directly. I'm I right?

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Yes.  Because there can be many different instances of `shared_ptr` pointing to different parts of the object (so `get()` returns a different value for each), but if all those parts share a common lifetime, all those `shared_ptr` instances must share the control block.

Comment: @BenVoigt: That depends on what you mean with _hold_. It does not hold a pointer to `B` directly, but through an intermediate struct (in the GCC implementation that is `_Sp_counted_base`, that is an abstract class with a couple of implementations, one holds a pointer to `B`, another conteins the `B` object itself, built with placement `new`.

Comment: @rodrigo: I'm not talking about the pointer to `B` -- that one *is* in the control block.  But the `A*` or `void*` returned by `ptr.get()` or `vptr.get()` is *not* in the control block, it is part of the `shared_ptr` instance.

Answer (score 4):

The `shared_ptr` always passes the original pointer to the deleter, not the one obtained through `vptr.get()`.  This is necessary not only to make this case work, but also to have pointers to member subobjects and owned objects as embodied in the constructor overload `shared_ptr<T>::shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>&, element_type*)`.

So this is safe.